# How to update many to many navigation property only?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4.1

i can update some properties use under method

```
public void Update(T entity, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] properties) 
{
    _dbSet.Attach(entity); 
    DbEntityEntry<T> entry = _context.Entry(entity);
    foreach (var selector in properties) { entry.Property(selector).IsModified = true; }
}
//repo.Update(entity, e => e.Name, e => e.Description);
```

but,i want to update navigation property only in many to many relationship
such like *admin role adminrole* i want to update adminrole table only

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update just relation you can use simple tricks.

To add a new relation between admin and role you need to do:

```
Admin admin = new Admin { Id = adminId };
context.Admins.Attach(admin);
Role role = new Role { Id = roleId };
context.Roles.Attach(role);
// Create new relation on attached entities
admin.Roles.Add(role);
context.SaveChanges();
```

To remove existing relation between admin and role you can try this:

```
Admin admin = new Admin { Id = adminId };
Role role = new Role { Id = roleId };
// Simulate existing relation on detached entities
admin.Roles.Add(role);
context.Admins.Attach(admin);
// Remove existing relation on attached entities
admin.Roles.Remove(role);
context.SaveChanges();
```

In both scenarios you just need to know keys for admin and role.

Note: This is for scenario where you have real many-to-many (with junction table containing only keys).

Comment: SystemAdmin entity = base.GetByKey(admin.SAID);
            DbEntityEntry<SystemAdmin> entry = base.DataContext.Entry(entity);
            entity.AdminRoles.Clear();
            entry.Collection(a => a.AdminRoles).CurrentValue = admin.AdminRoles;